# Decimal Value not accepted on MySQL insert

Tags: php, mysql

When trying to do a simple insert in PHP to MySQL database, a value of '.5' is entered into the hours variable and is being ignored and set to 0 in the database. I've tried with the db datatype set to float or decimal. Neither work.

Here is my insert code:

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO timecarddetails (timecardId, tdate, hours, ot, ticketNumber, km, details) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if($stmt === false){
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' .$sql. ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
$stmt->bind_param('isiisis',$tcId,$JOBDATE[$key],$HOURS[$key],$OT[$key],$TICKET[$key],$KM[$key],$DETAILS[$key]);
$stmt->execute();
```

When I do a print of the sql statement it comes out like this:

INSERT INTO timecarddetails (timecardId, tdate, hours, ot, ticketNumber, km, details) VALUES (24,2019-11-04,.5, , 2019450202,,Dispatched ticket)

Below is my table structure:
[image]

Is there anything wrong with my syntax? If you need any further information, please let me know. Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $stmt->bind_param('isiisis', ...

`i` stands for integer values. For decimals, you need `d`.

Considering your table structure, you likely want:

```
$stmt->bind_param(
    'isddsds',
    $tcId,
    $JOBDATE[$key],
    $HOURS[$key],
    $OT[$key],
    $TICKET[$key],
    $KM[$key],
    $DETAILS[$key]
);
```

Comment: Thank you...quite the simple oversight!

Comment: Welcome @jd0117! Glad that it helped.